# Convert string as module

Tags: python, module, python-module

is there a way to turn a string to an module object? i want to to do a function call after doing an API request but I cant convert the string I got from the request to a module object

I have seen some code that could actually do it however it is done by importing the module.

```
        import controller.mipay.controller as mipay

        @api.route('/redirect')
        class Request(Resource):
            parser = RequestChecker()
            def post(self):
                req = self.parser.parse_args() # <---- JSON/Dictionary

                #method_to_call = getattr(mipay, req['PaymentEndpoint'])
                method_to_call = getattr(req['PaymentMethod'], req['PaymentEndpoint'])

                return method_to_call()
```

is there anyway to convert the string to a module object or anything I can do to the string so I could call my function

Answer (score 2):

Using `__import__` may be the solution:

```
module = __import__("module.path")
```

See [importlib — The implementation of import](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Comment: yeah, you can try it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I assume req['PaymentMethod'] is the module and req['PaymentEndpoint'] is the method. What you can do is use importlib.

```
#import controller.mipay.controller as mipay
import importlib

my_mapping = {'mipay':'controller.mipay.controller'}

class Request(Resource):
    parser = RequestChecker()

    def post(self):
        req = self.parser.parse_args()  # <---- JSON/Dictionary

        # method_to_call = getattr(mipay, req['PaymentEndpoint'])
        mipay= importlib.import_module(my_mapping[req['PaymentMethod']])
        method_to_call = getattr(mymodule, req['PaymentEndpoint'])

        return method_to_call()
```

Comment: I am getting an error of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mipay

Comment: I see, you actually want to import 'controller.mipay.controller'. Best way to do it is via a dictionary. Answer updated above.